# How to create a date field for mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date, form-fields

How do I create a date field in angular/html to force the user to input the date in a specific format like MM/yyyy without any validation?

For example: when the user enters the first two digits of month, he should see a slash '/' so that he can enter only 4 more digits for year.

I know it can be done with a simple regex validation, but that will allow the user to enter the date in any format and then validate to show the error.

Comment: What is the type of field that you want? Is it an input type text or date?

Comment: Why annoy the user with useless UI features? Just tell them the required format, let them enter something and provide hints if it doesn't it the pattern once they've finished.

Comment: @Yatin: the field type is not a restriction.

Comment: @RobG : With all the formats available for date and with different standards for regions it gets important to force a user to input the date in a format that is required which is better than accepting a format and then annoying them with validation errors

Comment: In that case I recommend using a placeholder to inform the user to enter the date in mm/yyyy format and add a custom validation to check if it's a valid month and year (I know you don't want validations) so that the user doesn't enter something impossible like 25/0011 (the year may still be possible but not the month).

Comment: MM/YYYY is an unusual format anyway. Attempting to format as the user types using javascript is a sure way to end up with something that is, at best, quirky. At worst it will be dysfunctional for some users. Those types of UI features need a lot of code to cover all the possibilities and some just can't be accommodated. E.g. user types "10", script inserts a "/", they type "1", then realise "10" should be "09" so use cursor keys to go back, delete the "1" in "10" intending to add a "9" after the zero. What does your script do?

Comment: @RobG : MM/yyyy is not a unusual format. 
As for the example the script in that case should just allow the user to enter the new date without any problems. Regex can be used for this case.
Check out the first answer in this question:

[Javascript for date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471095/custom-date-input-field-without-any-datepicker)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fiddling with Javascript and HTML code I would suggest you take a look at some of the baked-in `date parser` directives offered by [angular-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) as a starting point and tweak things from there.

Example 1:
[Date parser](https://plnkr.co/edit/wCkLzQKQUWg7v1aeGK6k?p=preview)

Example 2:
[Date picker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eyDuhxWbXve0akAoYgzx?p=preview)

Example 3:
[Date picker with popup](https://plnkr.co/edit/trEE4VS9P4J6Pa3PIk14?p=preview)

As requested by OP. He is looking at inputting Month/Year only. This example might be more relevant;

[Example 4](http://plnkr.co/edit/cp6EnSyn5vY08ZwjjDca?p=preview)

Comment: Example 1: Its similar to using validations.
Example 2 and 3 : Would allow the user to enter in dd/mm/yyyy format where as i dont want the date to be picked. just the month and year

Comment: @Vishal--JAVA--CQ I did some research on your behalf and found this. http://plnkr.co/edit/cp6EnSyn5vY08ZwjjDca?p=preview 
It only has Month/Year selector

Comment: This works for the requirement but it stil has the issue of some old browsers and devices dont support date pickers! Also the voice commands cannot be used to fill in the date picker.
I am therefore not looking for a datepicker.
Thanks for your work though! Appriciate it